# How to find the range of $\sqrt {x^2-5x+4}$ where x is real.

Tags: functions

How to find the range of $$\sqrt {x^2-5x+4}$$ where $x$ is real.

What I've tried:

Let $\sqrt {x^2-5x+4}=y$, solving for real $x$, as $x$ is real discriminant must be $D\geq0$. Solving I get $y^2\geq\frac{-9}{4}$. Which I suppose implies all real . But on wolfram alpha it says $y\geq0$. What am I doing wrong.

Any help appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is a very common one. Namely, what you did was transforming:

$$\sqrt{x^2-5x+4} = y$$

to:

$$x^2-5x+4 = y^2$$

Now, indeed, any solution $(x,y)$ of the first equation will produce one of the second. *But*, $z^2 = y^2$ does *not* imply $z =y$. It only implies $z = \pm y$. So it will have to be determined which of the two cases applies.

Some of the solutions you found to the quadratic actually correspond to cases where $\sqrt{x^2-5x+4} = -y$. This is because, by definition, the square root is always positive. Therefore, if $y < 0$, we can't have that $\sqrt{x^2-5x+4} = y$ -- it must be the $-y$ case.

I hope that clears the air for you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the domain of the function is $(-\infty,1]\cup [4, \infty)$, since

$$ y=\sqrt{(x-1)(x-4)}, $$

which tells you that $y\geq 0$

**Note:** Compare with the function

> $$y=\sqrt{x}.$$

Comment: @Downvoter: What's the down vote for? Can you tell us the reason for the down vote.

Comment: Where is the range?